# Returning SAS ‘Return Code’ Aka %SYSRC to parent python script

Tags: python-2.7, sas, aix

I’m having trouble checking for errors in python’s subprocess. The subprocess is a sas program. Any wizards have any magic to share? I’d like to avoid searching the sas log for strings and instead rely on the return code.

I’m stuck w/ python 2.7 on a AIX server.

I’m able to invoke a sas program in a variety of ways using python’s subprocess module. I’ve successfully invoked a program using the check_output module, the Popen module or even just the call object. However, for the life of me I cannot get the return code!

```
Import subprocess
Subprocess.call([‘SAS’,’/path/program.sas’])
```

Or

```
Import subprocess
P = subprocess.check_output(“sas /path/program.sas”, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
Print(p)
```

Or
    Import subprocess
    P = subprocess.Popen(“sas /path/program.sas”, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    proc.wait()
    Standard_output, standard_error = proc.communicate*(
    Print(proc.returncode)
Or

```
Import subprocess
Try:
  output = subprocess.check_output(‘sas /path/program.sas’, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=true)
Except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
  Print(“Status : Fail”, exc.returncode)
```

[Python 2.7 Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

[SAS Completion Status](http://Support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#retcode.htm)

Comment: Does it work with simpler programs like `true` and `false`?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond the 3rd example will return errors with simple Unix commands such as ls - l [non existent file], but I’m not getting the errors returned from sas programs.

Comment: Does it work from shell? `SAS ...; echo ReturnStatus=$?` it should print 0 for success, non-zero for failure.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond haven’t tried this, but I like your idea. Thanks! I’ll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond thanks again for the tip! It helped me get to the source of my issue (user error). I posted the answer below.

Comment: Have you considered using `saspy` (or the Viya version if you have SAS Viya)?  Might make this easier, as then SAS is just basically a python library.  Open source library created by SAS employees, all code is on github or several major python library databases including pip.

Comment: @Joe I appreciate your response too! Yes, I’d love to use saspy, but sadly it’s not available to me currently. The office is strict.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad.  Given that it's the official way to connect to SAS using Python I'd hope they'd understand - good luck getting them to change their minds someday...

Comment: @Joe working on it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I kept receiving a return code of 0 or ‘’. This was happening, because of my sas program. See, my program was nothing more than an invalid libname reference.

```
Libname x ‘blah’;
```

This was returning 0 when I expected 2. I added abortabend to my program a viola python returned 2.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(“sas /path/program.sas;” shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
proc.wait()
standard_output, standard_error = proc.communicate()

print(proc.returncode)
```

Note that you may need to setup your autoexec and config vars or define them in your command.